# Why does $dq = \lambda (t+dt)dz - \lambda (t)dz = d\lambda dz$?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, charge

I am having trouble understanding why $$\frac{dq}{dt} = I(z) - I(z+dz) = -dI dz.$$

The question:  There is an infinite wire along the z-direction.  The current in the wire depends on $z$, and the charge density of the wire depends on time $t$.  i.e $I(z)$ and $\lambda (t)$.

I suspected that $dq = \lambda (t) dz$ as a small charge would just be the charge density at some time $t$ times a small length.  However, the correct answer is $$dq = \lambda (t+dt) dz - \lambda (t) dz = d\lambda dz.$$

**So my question is** why does $$dq = d\lambda dz$$ instead of $$\lambda(t) dz~?$$

Comment: This question will be much easier to answer if you provide a reference to the notes or textbook where these manipulations appear.

Comment: Griffiths 4ed question 7.59

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing the small charge $dQ(t)=\lambda (t)dz$  of the small piece $dz$ and ***the variation over time*** of this small charge : $dQ(t+dt)-dQ(t)=\left( \lambda (t+dt)-\lambda (t) \right)dz$

This variation in time is associated with the net current which is entering the charged small piece.

Answer (score 0):

You will agree that total charge q on the wire at time t can be writen as

[image]

Differentiating both sides with respect to t and using Leibnitz theorem :

[image]

I think if you expand you dλ term with respect to both z and t you should get your answer .

Comment: I agree with $q = \int \lambda dz$.  Differentiating both sides with respect to t gives $\frac {dq}{dt} = \frac {d}{dt} \int \lambda dz$, then using leibnitz rule $\frac {dq}{dt} = \int \frac {d \lambda}{dt} dz$, how does this equal the equation in your answer?